# Error: 'GetAuthenticationStateAsync was called before SetAuthenticationState.'

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-identity, blazor, telerik-reporting

I have a blazor project in which I am using dependency injection to use AuthenticationStateProvider.

I am getting the error :
'GetAuthenticationStateAsync was called before SetAuthenticationState.

I have two services:

1. ServiceClass which returns the identity of the user.
2. IReportServiceConfiguration returns a report from the database(xml string) using another service.

Report resolver is indirectly dependent on ServiceClass and this is the registration in startup.cs :

```
  services.AddScoped<IServiceClass, ServiceClass>();
        services.AddScoped<IReportServiceConfiguration>(sp =>
            new ReportServiceConfiguration
            {

                ReportingEngineConfiguration = sp.GetService<IConfiguration>(),


                HostAppId = "Html5DemoAppCore",
                Storage = new FileStorage(),
                ReportSourceResolver = sp.GetService<CustomReportSourceResolver>(),
            }
            ); ;
```

Code for the service class:

```
 public class ServiceClass : IServiceClass
{
    public ServiceClass(AuthenticationStateProvider authenticationStateProvider)
    {

        _authenticationStateProvider = authenticationStateProvider;

    }
    private readonly AuthenticationStateProvider _authenticationStateProvider;
    private string authuser = "";
    public async Task<string> GetIdentity()
    {
        var result = "";
        try
        {
            var authState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            var user = authState.User;
            IEnumerable<Claim> claims = user.Claims;

            if (authState != null)
            {
                result = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress").Value;
                authuser = result;
            }
            else
                result = authuser;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToSafeString()); }
        return result;
    } 
}
```

**FULL CYCLE**

getIdentity() of service class is called many times since startup of application and it runs fine.
But when this razor component is run

```
<ReportViewer ViewerId="rv1"
      
          ServiceUrl="/api/reports"
          
        ReportSource="@(new ReportSourceOptions()
                          {
                              Report = "reportAccountingGeneralLedger",
                              Parameters= new Dictionary <string,object>
                              {}
                          })"
          Parameters="@(new ParametersOptions { Editors = new EditorsOptions { MultiSelect = EditorType.ComboBox, SingleSelect = EditorType.ComboBox } })"
          ScaleMode="@(ScaleMode.Specific)"
          Scale="1.0" />
```

The part Report = "reportAccountingGeneralLedger" is resolved through ReportServiceConfiguration service that we have registered in startup.cs. (which uses CustomReportSourceResolver class to get the report xml definition from database and return report source using it, code below)

```
class CustomReportSourceResolver : IReportSourceResolver
{

    public CustomReportSourceResolver(IServiceClass sc, IReportConnectionStringManager csm)
    {
        userClass = sc;
        conStrMan = csm;
        //_scopeFactory = sc;
    }
    private readonly IServiceClass userClass;
    private readonly IReportConnectionStringManager conStrMan;
    public Telerik.Reporting.ReportSource Resolve(string reportName, OperationOrigin operationOrigin, IDictionary<string, object> currentParameterValues)
    {
        var report = string.Empty;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(reportName))
        {

            using (var context = new DataContext(userClass))
            {
                report = (from table in context.Reports where table.Name == reportName select table.Definition).First();
            }
        }
        ReportSource updatedReport;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(report))
        {
            throw new System.Exception("Unable to load a report with the specified ID: " + reportName);

        }
        else
        {
            XmlReportSource retreivedReport = new Telerik.Reporting.XmlReportSource { Xml = report };
            updatedReport = conStrMan.UpdateReportSource(retreivedReport);
        }
        return updatedReport;
    }
}
```

The code of datacontext:

```
 public class DataContext : DbContext
{

    public DataContext(IServiceClass sc)
    {

        serviceClass = sc;
    }
    private readonly IServiceClass serviceClass;
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(serviceClass.getUserConnectionString().Result);
    }
object1..object2.. object3....
}
```

For getting the report through database it uses datacontext as can be seen from the above code. Datacontext has dynamic connection string that's why execution goes to getIdentity() method in service class, and there we get the message in subject.

Comment: Could you please post the code of the ServiceClass service...

Comment: @enet I have added the code to the post. There are other methods in it but I just posted the problematic method.

Comment: @enet it is difficult to host this on github because there is some paid subscriptions/sources used in the project which wont compile unless you buy them. Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Never done that before. I guess there are other web sites where you can host your code for download. I just want to see the relevant code. If you can't find a way to upload your app, just post here the relevant code, which you can later on delete it.

Comment: Added more code to explain further

Comment: @enet Do you need more information that I am missing ?

Comment: See my answer...

Comment: @enet Did answer get deleted?